# Serve theme and plugins assets from correct domain on multi-domain multisite

Tags: multisite, domain, domain-mapping

I am having a problem with serving static theme assets and plugins assets from the correct domain on our multisite sage website. We have 2 different domains for the multisite. The first domain is maindomain and the second is let’s say otherdomain

So everything works okay when we are on our main multisite with domain maindomain. But when we visit otherdomain, there is a problem with fonts (and other static assets), because they are being served from maindomain, not otherdomain

Sage theme dist are served from `maindomain.com/app/sage-theme/dist/..` 
instead of `otherdomain.com/app/sage-theme/dist/..`

Plugins are served from `maindomain.com/app/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-assets` instead of `otherdomain.com/app/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-assets`

Images are served from `maindomain.com/app/uploads/sites/2` instead of `otherdomain.com/app/uploads/sites/2`

I did come across a WordPress ticket that could be related to the problem: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25650

But I am not entirely sure if it’s not the problem in the Sage theme itself…

Here is the config:

```
Config::define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
Config::define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
Config::define('COOKIEPATH', '');
Config::define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');

Config::define('WP_DEBUG', false);
Config::define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
Config::define('WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
Config::define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', false);
Config::define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);

Config::define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
Config::define('MULTISITE', true);
Config::define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
Config::define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'maindomain.com');
Config::define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
Config::define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
Config::define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

All info and feedback will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How are you serving the fonts? I don't see any font loading code in your question, can you update it to explain how the fonts are being loaded/included on the page? I read the linked Trac ticket, but I also don't see any use of the `switch_to_blog` and `restore_blog` functions in your question. Please update your question using the edit button, there isn't enough information to answer this

Comment: Its the problem of serving the dist folder where there are all assets of the Sage (Roots) theme and serving all plugins files. The fonts alone are not only problem. I edited and added path from where are assets served

Comment: It's likely because you set `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`, that Trac ticket is unrelated to your problem

Comment: @TomJNowell so the correct practice is to leave `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` empty on multi-domain multisite?

Comment: Try not defining it

Comment: But keep in mind, your use of sage means you're using a non-standard WP folder structure and URLs, so a generic WP answer may not work for you

Comment: @TomJNowell i tried your way, but it did not fixed the problem. Yeah that's why I wrote that I think it could be the Sage theme problem itself.

Comment: hmm if it is you'll need to ask in a Sage community

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for your help. I posted a topic in Roots Discourse.